# How to split PDF document into small ones

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, itext, itext7

I need to split a document into several small documents. For example, if document has 7 pages I need to generate 7 pdfs.

In iTextSharp I was using the following code, works pretty well. However, in iText 7 its not possible to do it in the same way.

###iTextSharp old code

```cs
var reader = new PdfReader(src);
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    var document = new Document();
    var copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(result + i + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();
    copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i));
    document.Close();
}
```

###iText 7, but not working

**First problem**
I have found that there is `PdfSplitter`, which could split my pdf into small pdfs. However, even my testing pdf has 7 pages and even `GetNumberOfPages()` returns number 7, number of split documents is just one.

In this [linked documenation](https://developers.itextpdf.com/ja/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/clone-splitting-pdf-file) is somehow shown how to split document. However, I have no idea how to make similar method to the one mentioned - `getNextPdfWriter`

**Second problem**
Even I have one file, its empty. I am wondering how to set proper writer to create correct pdf. Respectively, how to set reader in order to read the content of split document.

```cs
string result = outputPath + @"/page00";
using (pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfPath)))
{

    var splitter = new PdfSplitter(pdfDocument);
    var splittedDocs = splitter.SplitByPageCount(pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages());

    for (int i = 0; i < pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
    {
        //how to set reader to read the content of split docs. Or how to set writer for split doc.
        var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new FileStream(result + i + ".pdf", FileMode.Create)));
        pdfDoc.Close();
        splittedDocs[i].Close();
    }
}
```

##Question
How to properly split document into small ones in .NET core with iText 7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, it was quite easy. According to linked documentation I did the following:

Create custom splitter overriding functionality of PdfSplitter.

```cs
class CustomSplitter : PdfSplitter
{
      private int _order;
      private readonly string _destinationFolder;
    
      public CustomSplitter(PdfDocument pdfDocument, string destinationFolder) : base(pdfDocument)
      {
          _destinationFolder = destinationFolder;
          _order = 0;
      }
    
      protected override PdfWriter GetNextPdfWriter(PageRange documentPageRange)
      {
           return new PdfWriter(_destinationFolder + "splitDocument1_" +  _order++ + ".pdf");
      }
}
```

Then just use it for splitting a PDF document. Dont forget to close splitted document. And I would like to point out one thing.  `SplitByPageCount` - it takes number according to wich should be splitted. `SplitByPageCount(1)` split a PDF document by one page. I trully misunderstood this method.

```cs
using (var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("doc.pdf")))
{
     var outputDir = @"C:\";
     var splitter = new CustomSplitter(pdfDoc, outputDir);
     var splittedDocs = splitter.SplitByPageCount(1);

     foreach (var splittedDoc in splittedDocs)
     {
         splittedDoc.Close();
     }
}
```

The result is a few pdfs.

Comment: +1 on the `SplitByPageCount(1)` throwing me off as well.  I wrongly assumed that it wanted how many total pages it should be split within the source PDF.  I was wrong and thankfully you saved me a headache!

Comment: How do you keep this all in memory?  I have created a CustomSplitter using a MemoryStream, but I cannot seem to get to the stream after that in order to save it somewhere else.