# PdfException on iText7 when splitting a Pdf into pages

Tags: vb.net, itext7

Next code should split a multipage pdf file into one file each page.
It works for first page, but when closing destination pdfDocument for second page it throws iText.Kernel.PdfException: 'Document has no pages.'
Tried with different source files with same result.
Tried also to first get the pagecount and open the reader for each page with same result

```
Shared Function splitFileIntoPages(sourceFilename As String) As Boolean
    If System.IO.File.Exists(sourceFilename) Then

        Using reader As New PdfReader(sourceFilename)
            Using pdfSource As New PdfDocument(reader)
                For iPage = 1 To pdfSource.GetNumberOfPages
                    Dim destFilename = sourceFilename.Replace(".pdf", String.Format(".Page {0}.pdf", iPage))
                    Using writer As New PdfWriter(destFilename)
                        Using pdfDest As New PdfDocument(writer)
                            pdfSource.CopyPagesTo(iPage, 1, pdfDest)
                        End Using
                    End Using
                Next
            End Using
        End Using

    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, can you attach a sample document to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Well, I've just solved it thanks to @Arsiwaldi at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930344/how-to-split-pdf-document-into-small-ones

Comment: I'm posting my Vb.Net aproach

Answer (score 0):

The key was to inherit from PdfSplitter and overload the method GetNextPdfWriter to have a custom filename for the result files:

```
Class CustomSplitter
    Inherits PdfSplitter

    Private _pageIdx As Integer
    Private ReadOnly _sourceFilename As String

    Shared Function splitFileIntoPages(sourceFilename As String) As Boolean
        If System.IO.File.Exists(sourceFilename) Then
            Dim destinationFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(sourceFilename)
            Using pdfSource As New PdfDocument(New PdfReader(sourceFilename))
                Dim oSplitter = New CustomSplitter(pdfSource, sourceFilename)
                Dim oSplittedDocs = oSplitter.SplitByPageCount(1)

                For Each oSplittedDoc In oSplittedDocs
                    oSplittedDoc.Close()
                Next
            End Using
        End If
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Sub New(ByVal pdfDocument As PdfDocument, ByVal sourceFilename As String)
        MyBase.New(pdfDocument)
        _sourceFilename = sourceFilename
        _pageIdx = 0
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function GetNextPdfWriter(ByVal documentPageRange As PageRange) As PdfWriter
        _pageIdx += 1
        Dim filename = _sourceFilename.Replace(".pdf", String.Format(".Page {0}.pdf", _pageIdx))
        Return New PdfWriter(filename)
    End Function
End Class
```

usage:

```
CustomSplitter.splitFileIntoPages("mysourcefile.pdf")
```