# How can I split a long pdf page into several pages with iText7 in C# in different lengths?

Tags: c#, pdf, split, itext

I have pdf files in receipt format (e.g. 80x1000mm), one long page per document.
I want to create a new pdf and split the receipt into several printable A4 pages.
The receipt contains blocks (e.g. QR.Codes) which must not be cut in the middle.
So the new pages must be created based on given lengths (rectangles) (measured from the top edge). e.g.
Page 1: 0 - 272mm
Page 2: 272 - 513mm
Page 3: 513 - 783 mm
Page 4: 783 - to end

How can I split the pdf page into several pages with iText7 in c# by specifying rectangels?

looked at several examples (git TileClipped.java, C06E02_TheGoldenGateBridge_Tiles)

I have created a very simple example to play around with coordinates, AddXObjectAt, PdfCanvas AffineTransform, ConcatMatrix, Clip etc..
The example generates a 1000mm long pdf.
I have experimented with this pdf. For the beginning I just tried to cut 4 x 250mm.

**Unfortunately without success.**

```
using System;using iText.Commons;using iText.Kernel;using iText.Kernel.Colors;using iText.Kernel.Font;using iText.Kernel.Geom;using iText.Kernel.Pdf;using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas;using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Xobject;using iText.Layout;using iText.Layout.Element;

namespace SplitPage
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public const string fileReceipt = "c:\\tmp\\receipt1000mm.pdf";
        public const string fileA4 = "c:\\tmp\\receiptA4.pdf";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().CreateAndSplitPdfReceipt();
        }

        static float mmToPt(float mm) => mm * 72.0f / 25.4f;

        void CreateAndSplitPdfReceipt()
        {
            float recieptLength = 2834.6f;          // 1000mm approx 2834.6 pt
            float recieptWidth = 220f;              // approx 78mm

            // Create 1000mm long receipt (= 2834.6pt)
            {
                PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(fileReceipt));
                pdfDoc.SetDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(recieptWidth, recieptLength));
                Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

                for (int i = 1; i <= 250; i++)
                {
                    float y = recieptLength - mmToPt(i * 4f);    // 4mm per row  *  250rows = 1000mm 

                    var p = new Paragraph(string.Format("Row {0}: y={1:f1}    y'={2}mm ", i, y, i*4));
                    p.SetFontSize(8);
                    p.SetFixedPosition(10, y, 220);
                    p.SetMargin(0);

                    doc.Add(p);
                }
                pdfDoc.Close();
            }


            // split receipt1000.pdf in 4 equal parts a 250mm  
            {
                float chunk = recieptLength / 4f;

                PdfDocument srcDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(fileReceipt));
                PdfDocument pdfA4 = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(fileA4));
                pdfA4.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);

                PdfPage srcPage = srcDoc.GetPage(1); // just one page in receipt

                PdfFormXObject copyObject = srcPage.CopyAsFormXObject(pdfA4);
              
                PdfPage pageA4;
                PdfCanvas canvas;

                // 1st
                pageA4 = pdfA4.AddNewPage(PageSize.A4);
                canvas = new PdfCanvas(pageA4);
                canvas.AddXObjectAt(copyObject, 0, 3 * chunk);

                // 2nd
                pageA4 = pdfA4.AddNewPage(PageSize.A4);
                canvas = new PdfCanvas(pageA4);
                canvas.AddXObjectAt(copyObject, 0, 2 * chunk);

                // 3rd
                pageA4 = pdfA4.AddNewPage(PageSize.A4);
                canvas = new PdfCanvas(pageA4);
                canvas.AddXObjectAt(copyObject, 0, 1 * chunk);

                // 4th
                pageA4 = pdfA4.AddNewPage(PageSize.A4);
                canvas = new PdfCanvas(pageA4);
                canvas.AddXObjectAt(copyObject, 0, 0);

                srcDoc.Close();
                pdfA4.Close();    }}}}
```

My problem is obviously that I did not understand the basic operations.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930344/how-to-split-pdf-document-into-small-ones

Comment: i don't think so.
I don't want to split a document with multiple pages into multiple documents with one page.
I want to divide a page into different sized parts